# Flexible syntax highlighter written in C#

Tags: c#, html, xhtml, syntax-highlighting

Is there an open source project written using C# which can apply syntax highlighting to a wide range of languages in a similar way to shjs?

Here is some pseudo code:

```
public string HighlightSourceInHTML(string html) {
    return Highlighter.HighlightHTML(html);
}
```

Where input HTML would be something along the lines of:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>...</head>
<body>
    <p>Here is a function written using C#:</p>
    <pre class="source lang-csharp">public void foo(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}</pre>

    <p>Here is the same function written using JavaScript:</p>
    <pre class="source lang-javascript">function foo(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Where the above would essentially return the entire HTML file where all `pre` elements with class `source` are syntax highlighted where source language is defined

**Note:** This is not for a server-side script but rather is part of an offline application where performance is less important.

Comment: I was going to suggest [Pygments](http://pygments.org/) (which is what Ma9ic's answer uses), which is written in Python. Does the syntax highlighter *have* to be written in C#? There are a number of syntax highlighters written in other languages: [Google code prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/), [highlight.js](http://softwaremaniacs.org/soft/highlight/en/) and [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/) to name a few.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found one! There was one on my HDD the whole time in the Sandcastle Help File Builder (SHFB) folder in a managed DLL called "ColorizerLibrary.dll".

Simply add a reference to this DLL and syntax colouring becomes very easy.

Here is a usage example:

```
ColorizerLibrary.CodeColorizer colorizer = new ColorizerLibrary.CodeColorizer(
    @"C:\Program Files (x86)\EWSoftware\Sandcastle Help File Builder\Colorizer\highlight.xml",
    @"C:\Program Files (x86)\EWSoftware\Sandcastle Help File Builder\Colorizer\highlight.xsl"
);
colorizer.Init();

string htmlText = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Test Page</title></head><body><pre codelanguage=\"CSharp\">public string Foo(string a, int b = 4) {\n\treturn a + b * 3;\n}</pre></body></html>";
return colorizer.ProcessAndHighlightText(htmlText);
```

*Note: Remember to link to the CSS file in `head` to visualize syntax colours.*

**Added:** Please find source code for `ColorizerLibrary` from here: http://shfb.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/98645#1672960

Comment: I realize that this is a very old answer but, as the accepted answer, it has since failed to maintain its standards.

The link to the suggested library is broken. This answer relies exclusively on a resource that's only accessible by way of a link and the assumption that the link will not break. This is exactly why linking to 3rd party resources rather than posting code-based solutions is frowned upon and exactly why I'm down-voting this as a viable answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what your after, but it might help.

useful link:

http://hilite.me/

Comment: While I'm here from a google search, I may as well point out that this does, in no viable way, help answer or provide a solution to the actual question. "useful link" is anything but useful in the context of OP requesting an offline, C#-driven syntax highlighting solution.